# Is theoretical probability the mean of infinite empirical probabilities

Tags: probability

I am a high schooler so pardon if the question is non sensical.

If I run an experiments 'n' no. times, and organise them into groups of 100, will the mean of each group's empirical probability equal the experiment's theoretical probability

For example if  I flip a coin infinite number of times and calculate the empirical probability, find the mean, will it be equal to 1/2= 0.5

Comment: This is (largely) the content of [The Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).  You are right to think that it's not obvious.

Comment: Unlike lulu, I read the question as a philosophical one, about the definition of a theoretical probability distribution.  The answer is "yes", in the sense that experts have used the idea of an infinite experiment as a way to connect the mathematical theory with real-world experiences.